# Limit calculation to infinity

Tags: calculus

The limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left | \operatorname{exp}\left(\frac{2\pi ik}{n}\right) -\operatorname{exp}\left(\frac{2\pi i(k-1)}{n}\right)\right |$$  is

(A) 2 (B) 2e (C) 2$\pi$ (D) 2i.

Any pointers as to how to approach this problem ? Is any specific theorem/result within calculus required to solve this ?

Comment: Can you interpret the sum geometrically?

Answer (score 0):

The expression inside the summation is $$\left|\exp(2\pi i(k-1/2)/n)\left(\exp\left(\frac{i\pi}{n}\right)-\exp\left(\frac{-i\pi}{n}\right) \right)\right|=2\left|\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\right|$$ So, the expression becomes $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}2n\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)=2\pi$$ Note that geometrically it means the perimeter of a regular polygon with $n$ sides inscribed in a unit circle cnetered at the origin. So as $n\rightarrow\infty$ the perimeter tends to the perimeter of the circle which is $2\pi$.

Comment: Maybe you can also prove the estimates $\sin(2\pi/n)\leqslant \left | \operatorname{exp}\left(\frac{2\pi ik}{n}\right) -\operatorname{exp}\left(\frac{2\pi i(k-1)}{n}\right)\right |\leqslant \frac{2\pi}{n}$. This is maybe a little more geometric and implies the same result of course, since the upper and the lower bound converge (when summed up) to $2\pi$ as $n$ tends to infinity. @Samrat: Sorry I had troubles editing :-).

Comment: Which estimates?